# Фильтры в сервлетах

Tags: java-ee, java, сервлеты

Изучаю Java EE. Подскажите, пожалуйста, примеры кода и приложения с использованием фильтров в сервлетах. Спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Фильтры существуют уже довольно давно, так что примеров просто море

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/05/10/servlet_filters.html

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/interceptingfilter-142169.html

Вот очень хороший пример о том, как рулить HTTP-заголовками с помощью фильтров:

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/03/03/filters.html?page=1

Вот пример использования для контроля доступа:

http://www.developer.com/security/article.php/3467801/Securing-J2EE-Applications-with-a-Servlet-Filter.htm

Вот пример фильтра для добавления gzip-сжатия (glassfish и так его поддерживает, но с некоторыми особенностями):

http://www.tidytutorials.com/2010/03/java-servlet-proxy-with-compression.html

Тут просто солянка из нескольких применений:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html